# Graph API Explorer token vs own application token. Same permissions, different response

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm currently working on an Android application that'll need to display the user's stream. The code for this is in place and working fine, but I noticed I would get empty responses after about three successive calls to /me/home with the "until" parameter set correctly. The increasing the "limit" parameter has no effect, but the Graph API Explorer is able to make the call same call (with it's own access token) just fine.

I narrowed down the cause of the empty response to the access token, and I can consistently reproduce it in the Graph API Explorer. When I request a token through the explorer with "Graph API Explorer" selected as application in the upper right, the calls always return the correct result. However, as soon as I use my own app (still in the explorer) the very same request returns an empty "data" array. I can also use the former token in my own application and get the results I want.

UPDATE: To clarify what works and what does not, this is what I get with a token for my own app

```
this works  : me/home?until=1372587386&limit=10
this doesn't: me/home?until=1372587385&limit=10
```

Notice the until parameter is a second earlier? The first request returned 10 entries, including ones posted earlier than the date supplied in my second request. This does not occur when I use the token from the Graph API Explorer application.

Both tokens have the "read_stream" permission, and a call to https: //graph.facebook.com/me/permissions confirms this. The only variable is the application that the token is for. The app's configuration on Facebook seems fine to me:

[image]

Is this a limitation of "Sandbox Mode", or is there something else that's causing my own tokens to result an empty response?

Comment: I submitted a bugreport here:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/178950022281727

The people over at Facebook are apparently looking into it.

Comment: subscribed. Same problem

Comment: According to Facebook this is "By Design", and they won't be fixing it. See bug report linked to above...

Comment: Have the same problem [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20162060/facebook-api-pagination-doesnt-work/20166249)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with read_stream! And it's not a sandbox mode limitation because in my case sandbox mode is off and still I get inconsistent results from Graph Api Explorer.

Comment: Next time post things like this as a comment to the original question! I added a link to the Facebook bugreport as such a comment, it would be great if you could you could add yourself as a subscriber there!